# HTML output via Theme Customizer is not working

Tags: theme-customizer

Well here I am again with a problem that I just can't seem to figure out. I have searched and searched, found answers but I just can't seem to get this to work.

I have a theme called WP-Forge and it uses the theme customizer extensively. One of the options available to users is to add or modify the copyright text in the footer. This could be something as simple as them changing the year or company name but more often than not people like to add a link to a site. I keep getting emails about html not outputting the way it should. So I would like to figure this out.

In the theme customizer of WP-Forge I have the following setting and control:

```
  $wp_customize->add_setting('wpforge_footer_text',array(/* footer text */
    'default' => '',
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'wpforge_sanitize_text',
    'priority' => 20,
  ));
  $wp_customize->add_control('wpforge_footer_text',array(
    'label' => __('Footer Text','wp-forge'),
    'section' => 'footer_content',
    'type' => 'textarea',
  ));
```

as you can see the sanitize callback is `wpforge_sanitize_text`. Here is the sanitize function:

```
  function wpforge_sanitize_text( $input ) {
      return wp_kses_post( force_balance_tags( $input ) );
  }
```

It works fine if you just enter in text. However, if I add the following:

```
Copyright © 2015 - <a href="http://somelinkhere.com">SomeLinkHere</a>
```

I get this in the preview window:

```
Copyright © 2015 - SomeLinkHere
```

Everything looks good so I then hit save and publish and look at the home page I see this:

```
Copyright © 2015 - <a href="http://somelinkhere.com">SomeLinkHere</a>
```

So what exactly am I missing? Can someone help me get this working the way I want it? Any help is greatly appreciated and I thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is this code and not their input?

Comment: I think the problem is, that after you've sanitized the input, the code that displays the link on the front end escapes the HTML again.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - as you can see from the example above the simple html I put in shows up the same way on the front end.

This is how I call the footer text in the footer

`<?php echo esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_footer_text')); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely a bit late, Tsquez, but [`esc_attr`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) is for attributes, e.g. `<a title="esc_attr( $title )">`. You could also sanitize the HTML in your footer with [`wp_kses_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/) instead.

Comment: No worries amigo, can you believe I just figured this out a few weeks ago.

I went with 

`<?php echo wp_kses_post(get_theme_mod( 'wpforge_footer_text')); ?>`

Which works perfectly. Thanks for trying to help.